# JSON Schema - How to limit an object to specific name, with value type 'boolean', without using regex

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to record data from checkbox inputs, for example:

```js
{
  client 1: false,
  client 2: true,
  client 3: false,
}
```

or

```js
{
 dogs: true
 cats: true
 horses: false
}
```

I want to create simple JSON Schemas for these, and would prefer to use a system where I don't have to learn/type/read complicated regex. The following works quite nicely for example 1:

```json
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^Client [1-3]$": {
          type: "boolean",
        },
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
```

Unfortunately, it will be complicated when the object properties don't follow a simple pattern, as in example 2. Is there a way to strictly specify the object properties in an array, and also specify the value type? I want to limit the object property names only to the array. So I want something like this pseudo schema:

```json
   "additionalProperties": false,
   "propertyNames": ["Client 1", "Client 2", "Client 3"],
   "allValuesToBe": "boolean"
```

(I made the last keyword up, but want something like that.) This would accept/reject the following:

```js
  client 1: false, // accept
  foobar: true, // reject, bad prop name
  client 3: 123, // reject, bad value
```

Answer (score 4):

`additionalProperties` doesn't have to be a boolean - you can put a normal schema there. So as long as all your properties in this object follow the same guidelines, you can do:

```
"propertyNames": { "enum": ["Client 1", "Client 2", "Client 3"] },
"additionalProperties": { "type": "boolean" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also seems to permit `foobar: true,` so won't work in my case. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: No, it shouldn't permit that. `propertyNames` will fail if the property name is not one of the values specified in the enum. This keyword was added in draft 6.  https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#section-10.3.2.4

Comment: Ohhh. Crumbs. Yeah that explains it. I'm using Draft 04. Thanks so much for the help!